# function not being added to NAMESPACE

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I have a function that I'm trying to add to a package.  I am generating the documentation via `devtools::document()`.  The .Rd files for this and ~70 other functions are generated successfully, but this one function is not added to the namespace.

The file can be found at the following link, and perhaps importantly, is called [truncate.distribution.r](https://github.com/Beothuk/bio.utilities/blob/master/R/truncate.distribution.r).  I have many other functions with periods in the names, so I am almost certain that is not the problem.

However, as I was going through the NAMESPACE, I noticed this line `S3method(truncate,distribution)`, and wondered if the similar name was a coincidence (i.e. comma, as opposed to period).  I tried removing the period from the name, and re-generating the documentation and NAMESPACE, and it all worked just fine - that is, the function is exported with the package.

While the altered name works, I would like to learn why it failed and how I can prevent similar failures in the future.  Also, I like the original name. :)

Anyone have any thoughts?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note:  I think it is recommended to use a hyphen instead of a period for those types of names (i.e. truncate-distribution.r).

Comment: ... because the dot leads to the function being interpreted as a `S3methods(...)`.  In short, "don't do that".

Comment: A hyphen? I would have guessed an underscore. Hyphens are interpreted by the parser as "minus-signs".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you guys are right, and it had to do with the periods in the names.   The particular file that cause the problem for us was one where the first part of the name ("truncate."...) was already a base function, thus being interpreted as S3methods.

Thanks to all who answered.  I'm not sure why I'm getting voted down - knowing not to use periods in function names is not inherent knowledge, nor is it expressly forbidden anywhere I looked (i.e. [Hadley's](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html), or [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) Style Guides).

Answer (score 0):

I found one other potential cause of similar grief.  My last line of Roxygen code had a typo in the  `#' @export` command resulting in the same poor behavior

Comment: This doesn't seem like it directly answers the question, which was about punctuation allowed in function names, but you're talking about a typo in your documentation. There isn't any indication that the OP had a similar typo, and typo-based questions generally get closed as being off topic